# concatenate fields in another fields with auto refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I m new in rails and html....

I want to concatenate first name and last name in a field fullname in a view. I want that when you modify last name or first name, full name is automatically refreshed with 'first name' +" " + 'lastname'

I tried this but Ive an error. because, seems that full name field stays empty and I tried to make an alert in function to see if concatenation is working. But seems not to do it....

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      function test ()
      {

      $('fullname').value <= $('firstname').value + " " + $('lastname').value;
      }

  </script>


  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :prenom %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :firstname, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Prenom", class: "form-control",:onchange => "test()" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :lastname %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :nom, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Nom", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :fullname %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :fullname, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Full Name", class: "form-control", :readonly => true %> <!-- ajout de readonly -->
  </div>
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

You should check (or post to your question) your resulting html so I'll may help you more.

This is incorrect:

```
$('fullname').value <= $('firstname').value + " " + $('lastname').value;
```

Here the working example.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('input.firstname, input.lastname').on('input', function(e) {
          var changedFullName = $('input.firstname').val() + " " + $('input.lastname').val()
          $('input.fullname').val(changedFullName);
        });
      });
  </script>
  <label for="firstname">FirstName</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" class="firstname" /><br>
  <label for="lastname">LastName</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" class="lastname" /><br>
  <hr>
  <span>FullName</span><br>
  <input type="text" name="fullname" class="fullname" readonly />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. So I change to Ajax but Still issues to change my f.text_field to input ?  My Code begin with   <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

Comment: @PhilippeHaumesser is your resulting html looks similar to [this example](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html)?

Comment: hi thanks it works but I lost class="form-control". How can I get bootstrap class ?

Comment: in fact it does not work as it is the sign_up form with devise. It says tha firtname, last name and full name fields are empty when I click on submit